# Verifying certificates signed by intermediate CA

Tags: openssl, certificates

I am trying to figure out how to use OpenSSL to verify a certificate that has been signed by an intermediate CA which I have signed with my root CA. I tried concatenating the certificate with the intermediate and root certificates as I saw suggested in some places, but I still get an "unable to get local issuer certificate" error. What should I do?

For reference, the command I am using is as follows:

```
cat my_cert.crt intermediate_ca.crt root_ca.crt > cert_chain.crt
```

My certificates, when concatenated, look like:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Which I believe is the correct format. The error I get is: 
openssl verify -CAfile cacert.crt
cert_chain.crt: C = US, ST = State, O = Company, OU = Unit, CN = Common Name

Comment: Yes? What is the command you are using to concatenate?

Comment: cat my_cert.crt intermediate_ca.crt root_ca.crt > cert_chain.crt

Comment: Your certificates seem to be in DER format, do they start with a `BEGIN` line? If not, convert them to .pem based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files and then try the concatenation with the .pem files. If that does not work, please post error messages or more information in your question.

Comment: I've edited the post as I couldn't get it to format properly in a comment.